# Site name appearing in django URLs

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I'm having an issue where a call to the url template tag in Django is appending the site name (I don't want it in there.)

Let's say that the site name is 'mysite'.

So for example:

```
<a href="{% url myapp.views.myview "myparam" %}">Link text</a>
```

is producing:

```
<a href="/mysite/foo/bar">Link text</a>
```

when I want it to produce:

```
<a href="/foo/bar">Link text</a>
```

My urls.py is set up like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
import mysite.myapp.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/foo/bar/$', 'mysite.myapp.views.myview'),
)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit - when the site was in development, it was on a subdirectory of a test server, with the app as the subdirectory! So it was sitting on http://www.mytestserver.com/mysite. There's no caching in place, and all the references to /mysite were removed prior to going live.

Comment: What do you see when you go to manage sites in Django's admin interface?

Comment: @dominic, I just see example.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your modpython configuration, if you've got one.  There may be a line that looks like `PythonOption django.root /mysite`  Remove that.

Comment: Aha - this is very likely the culprit. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, i'll remember too that can happen :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, that this is the rendered version? [Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) say, that an absolute url should be produced, i.e. `/mysite/foo/bar`. Are you checking source in the browser? Try printing out the result of `render_to_string` (or other rendering function you are using) and check, if there example.com is added too.

Comment: You're quite right, I have edited my question for clarity. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I sincerely don't know, what's happening. I would have to take a look at the code.

Comment: By the way, why do you import import mysite.myapp.views in urls.py? You don't have to do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. Presumably that's because I'm passing it as a string, rather than passing the view directly?

Comment: Yep, you only need import, if you reference the imported name. If you put something into a string, you don't really reference it.